# Function expressions are not supported in decorators Consider changing the function expression into an exported function

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I'm trying to enable angularivy in my current project and while ng build i got this error.

```
ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(172,19): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
src/app/home/home.component.ts(95,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/home/home.component.ts(96,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/type'.
src/app/nomina/solicitudes/vacaciones/vacaciones.component.ts(56,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

I've checked some suggestion like making function in export and using it again to but error changed instead of being solved.

```
  ],
  exports: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard, 
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es' },
    CommonService, 
    {
      provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
      useFactory: () => new CustomNgbDateParserFormatter('longDate')
    },
```

It may build successfully if error solved

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `() => {}` with `function() {}` will help.

Comment: hey i have: useFactory: () => new CustomNgbDateParserFormatter('longDate')

Comment: are you suggesting to convert it into as below ?
useFactory: function() { return new CustomNgbDateParserFormatter('longDate'); }

Comment: please @user3875919 , let me know

Comment: Yes, lets try it out.

Comment: sorry, got busy with some other task, now its not needed, but thanks for suggesting.

Comment: it does help. Why would that not be supported?

Comment: Not sure why exactly but there are few things which do not work as expected after AOT compilation. Please refer [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.3xvtag7g9)

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the function like this before declaring your module

```
export function createCustomFormatter(): Function
{
  return () => new CustomNgbDateParserFormatter('longDate');
}
```

And then use that function in the provider

```
providers: [
  CommonService, 
  {
    provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
    useFactory: createCustomFormatter
  },
```

Comment: sorry, got busy with some other task, now its not needed, but thanks for suggesting.